# Plotting suitability map from points in Qgis

Tags: gis, qgis, pyqgis

I have a layer "fruit" plotted in points in a map over Africa. This layer contains two types of fruits and I need to analyse with a suitability map the presence of these fruits. I don't know which steps I should follow and I don't know where I can get a clear example of this.

I tried to vectorize but it doesn't work